# processo 24x5 no jar como converter para .war

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, jar, war

Criei um jar para calcular sinais de forex, porém gostaria de hospedá-lo em algum servidor na nuvem. Como andei pesquisando, será muito mais fácil converte-lo para um war.

Como meu app deve rodar 24x5, precisaria que rodasse nesse mesmo período, sem que eu precise efetuar nenhum comando para isso.

Já criei um projeto web, inicialmente em servlet, mas o problema principal:

no .jar eu coloquei um loop no Main e pronto...
no .war, onde eu poderia fazer algo parecido?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que entendi, você executa uma determinada ação de tempos em tempos, correto?

Acho que o Quartz resolve seu problema. Ele é basicamente um agendados de tarefas, semelhante ao CRON do Linux.

- [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)
- [Tutorial - Caelum](http://blog.caelum.com.br/agendamento-de-tarefas-em-aplicacoes-web-um-truque-com-quartz/)

Comment: Pelo que eu pesquisei, acho que resolve, vou testar. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Que bom! Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta!